# How to explicitly check the signature of numba's cfunc?

Tags: python, cython, numba

Numba offers functionality to create  fast C callbacks with [`cfunc`](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/cfunc.html), for example

```
import numba as nb
@nb.cfunc("float64(float64)")
def fun(x):
    return 2.0*x
```

This numba-`cfunc` could be used in Cython to pass C callback to wrapped C-code/other C-functionality, for example:

```
%%cython
ctypedef double(*f_type)(double)

# uses callback
cdef void c_print(double x, f_type f):
    print(f(x))

def evaluate_and_print(double x, f):
    # TODO: check signature of f
    # it is not possible to cast a Python object to a pointer directly,
    # so we cast the address first to unsigned long long
    c_print(x, <f_type><unsigned long long int>(f.address))
```

This works with the right type of `cfunc`s, i.e. `"float64(float64)"`. The problem is, that the above would also "work" with any `cfunc`-object, i.e. ones with wrong signature (e.g. `"int64(int64)"`), thus making strange things/crashes possible during the run time (but not raising a Python-exception).

To illustrate problem, consider the following `cfunc`:

```
import numba as nb
@nb.cfunc("int64(int64)")
def fun2(x):
    return 2.0*x
```

which now can be passed to `evaluate_and_print`:

```
evaluate_and_print(10, fun)
# 377110592.0
```

it doesn't crash, doesn't throw, but yields a strange result (whatever value was in `%xmm0`-register after the call to `fun2`, at least on my x64-machine). Obviously because this is a UB, for other functions/other architectures other things can happen.

How can be checked, that the `cfunc`-object has the right signature?

---

Note: one could probably use the `_sig`-attribute of the `cfunc`-object for comparison, but I would like to avoid using private API here.

Comment: Haven't tried it but would a test call with suitable data-types in a `try except` work? It's harder to check the return type from that though.

Comment: @DavidW I have added an example of what could happen (no Python-exception would be raised). I hope I understood your comment correctly...

Comment: I was suggesting calling it while it's still a numba function (where I assume there's a bit more protection?). I.e. call `f` in `evaluate_and_print` before you take the address. Obviously that does have side effects.

Comment: @DavidW, Ok `f.ctypes(x)`. This probably wouldn't work: I think passing an `int` to `float64(float64)` would not raise an exception, but it is not a `float64(int64)` after all...

Comment: Fair point - I think you're right.

Comment: You can check argtype (restype) of the passed cfunc object. eg. `f.ctypes.argtypes==(ctypes.c_double,)`. If you call the function many times from cython/C side it would make sense to do this only once.

Comment: @max9111 That sounds like exactly the answer that this question is after.

Comment: @max9111 maybe passing `f.ctypes` is a saner interface anyway: 1) it would work for any ctypes-function not only numba's cfuncs  2) it is what all other methods expect (e.g. `scipy.quad`) anyway 3) there is already machinery in place to check the signatures. It looks like, my idea to somehow use `nb.typing.templates.Signature`, isn't that bright after all...